# Chaining actions in angular RXJS

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I have a piece of code in my auth effects file. I want to chain actions but I'm not doing it right! I keep getting errors like I'm not dispatching the correct Action. I'm looking at all the different things I can use (mergeMap, switchMap and etc.) but everything's confusing for me. I need to learn a lot.

What I want to achieve is:
check to see if there is a token in local storage > if it is then call the api using the service to get the user by token > get the result and turn it into the proper user object that I'm using in the front end > dispatch the Login action with that user

The broken code is:

```
@Effect()
init$: Observable<Action> = defer(() => {
   const userToken = localStorage.getItem(environment.authTokenKey);
   let observableResult = of({type: 'NO_ACTION'});
   if (userToken) {

        return this.auth.getUserByToken().pipe(
        tap((res) => console.log('Got user by id: ', res)), 
        switchMap(() => merge(response => {
        return this.prepareUser(response, userToken)
   }, 
    map((user: User) => {
      return of(new Login(user));
    }
    ))));
}
return observableResult;
});


...

prepareUser(response: string, token: string): User {
let res = JSON.parse(response);
let userJson = res.sub;
let user: User = {
  id: userJson.id,
  firstName: userJson.firstName,
  lastName: userJson.lastName,
  email: userJson.email,
  password: userJson.password,
  phone: userJson.phone,
  role: userJson.role,
  status: userJson.status,
  _createdDate: userJson.createdDate,
  _updatedDate: userJson.updatedDate,
  accessToken: {idToken: token, expiresIn: 1800},
  refreshToken: token,
  pic: '',
  _isEditMode: false,
  _userId: userJson.id,
  clear: () => {}
}
return user;
```

}

PS. I don't know what the defer() is doing, someone else wrote that part of the code and I'm trying to add the functionality that I want.

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

So I kept on trying and trying and this worked for me, I thought to post it here just in case if it helps anyone else. 
I actually need to sit down and learn the RXJS properly so this answer might not be the proper way but its doing what I want it to do:

```
return  of({}).pipe(
    mergeMap(_ => this.auth.getUserByToken())
  ).pipe(
    map(response => this.prepareUser(response, userToken)),
    mergeMap(user => of(new Login(user)))
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { ofType, createEffect, ROOT_EFFECTS_INIT } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { EMPTY } from 'rxjs';

init$ = createEffect(() => 
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(ROOT_EFFECTS_INIT),
    switchMap(action => {
         const userToken = localStorage.getItem(environment.authTokenKey);
         if (userToken) {
          return this.auth.getUserByToken().pipe(
            map(response => this.prepareUser(response, userToken)),
            map(user => new Login(user))
          )
         } else {
          return EMPTY;
         }
    })
  )
);
```